# Bootstrap Responsive Carousel With Multiple Items pass 1 photo per click

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design

I'm working on a carousel with multiple images http://jsfiddle.net/Va8Un/10/

```
<div class="container-fluid">
<div class="row-fluid">
<div class="carousel slide" id="myCarousel">
        <div class="carousel-inner">
          <div class="item active">
                <ul class="thumbnails">
                    <li class="span3">
                        <div class="caption">
                            <h5>Caption</h5>
                        </div>
                        <div class="thumbnail">
                            <img src="http://placehold.it/260x180" alt="">
                        </div>
                    </li>
                    <li class="span3">
                        <div class="caption">
                            <h5>Caption</h5>
                        </div>
                        <div class="thumbnail">
                            <img src="http://placehold.it/260x180" alt="">
                        </div>
                    </li>
                    <li class="span3">
                        <div class="caption">
                            <h5>Caption</h5>
                        </div>
                        <div class="thumbnail">
                            <img src="http://placehold.it/260x180" alt="">
                        </div>
                    </li>
                    <li class="span3">
                        <div class="caption">
                            <h5>Caption</h5>
                        </div>
                        <div class="thumbnail">
                            <img src="http://placehold.it/260x180" alt="">
                        </div>
                    </li>
                </ul>
          </div>
          <div class="item">
                <ul class="thumbnails">
                    <li class="span3">
                        <div class="caption">
                            <h5>Caption</h5>
                        </div>
                        <div class="thumbnail">
                            <img src="http://placehold.it/260x180" alt="">
                        </div>
                    </li>
                    <li class="span3">
                        <div class="caption">
                            <h5>Caption</h5>
                        </div>
                        <div class="thumbnail">
                            <img src="http://placehold.it/260x180" alt="">
                        </div>
                    </li>
                    <li class="span3">
                        <div class="caption">
                            <h5>Caption</h5>
                        </div>
                        <div class="thumbnail">
                            <img src="http://placehold.it/260x180" alt="">
                        </div>
                    </li>
                    <li class="span3">
                        <div class="caption">
                            <h5>Caption</h5>
                        </div>
                        <div class="thumbnail">
                            <img src="http://placehold.it/260x180" alt="">
                        </div>
                    </li>
                </ul>
          </div>
          <div class="item">
                <ul class="thumbnails">
                    <li class="span3">
                        <div class="caption">
                            <h5>Caption</h5>
                        </div>
                        <div class="thumbnail">
                            <img src="http://placehold.it/260x180" alt="">
                        </div>
                    </li>
                    <li class="span3">
                        <div class="caption">
                            <h5>Caption</h5>
                        </div>
                        <div class="thumbnail">
                            <img src="http://placehold.it/260x180" alt="">
                        </div>
                    </li>
                    <li class="span3">
                        <div class="caption">
                            <h5>Caption</h5>
                        </div>
                        <div class="thumbnail">
                            <img src="http://placehold.it/260x180" alt="">
                        </div>
                    </li>
                    <li class="span3">
                        <div class="caption">
                            <h5>Caption</h5>
                        </div>
                        <div class="thumbnail">
                            <img src="http://placehold.it/260x180" alt="">
                        </div>
                    </li>
                </ul>
          </div>
        </div>
        <a data-slide="prev" href="#myCarousel" class="left carousel-control">‹</a>
        <a data-slide="next" href="#myCarousel" class="right carousel-control">›</a>
    </div>
```

I want to know if there's an implementation of a the bootsrap carousel like that one, but with the arrows passing one photo per click.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed the carousel to this ones http://caroufredsel.dev7studios.com/. It has a lot of features.